# UpdateDefinition with multiple fields not working

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, asp.net-core, mongodb-query

I try to build an update request using the C# mongodb driver.

I would like to update a field only if he is not null. Here is the following code :

```
public void Replace(Core.Entity.Project project)
{
    var filter = Builders<Entity.Project>.Filter.Eq(x => x.ProjectNumber, project.ProjectNumber);
    var update = BuildUpdateRequest(project);

    _mongoCollection.UpdateOne(filter, update);
}

private UpdateDefinition<Entity.Project> BuildUpdateRequest(Core.Entity.Project project)
{
    var builder = Builders<Entity.Project>.Update;
    var update = builder.Set(x => x.LastUpdateDate, DateTime.UtcNow);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(project.UserId))
    {
        update.Set(x => x.UserId, project.UserId);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately when I run my unit/integration tests, the data is not updated. 
Do you have a better way to use this objects ?

Comment: Maybe just add to the filter those conditions? then the document will only be matched if its valid for an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it was easy. Fixed it with :

```
update = update.Set(x => x.UserId, project.UserId);
```